# How to stick the menubar at the top of the window PyGTK

Tags: pygtk, menubar

How can i stick the menubar at the top of the window? 
[image]

I'm using a `Gtk.VBox` and i added `Gtk.MenuBar` inside. I'm using Gtk3

The code source : http://pastebin.com/YHZQLzZg

Thanks

Comment: please add more code especially your menu and  packing on  layout. Also see: https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

Comment: I will add it asap, what's the layout that i should be using ? I just used a VBox

Comment: i added the source code

Comment: Are you using xml files for the UI? If so you should show them

Comment: I'm using a python code;, see here http://pastebin.com/zAxtUdKw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was using

```
window.set_border_width(10)
```

i removed the border width and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by this that you want no titlebar ( just a menubar ), then you can try the Gtk set_decorated() function using False as a parameter.  On *some* systems that will allow a window with no titlebar ( and possibly other things that are standard ) to be created.  But it's not guaranteed to work as it is dependant on the window manager, not Gtk or Python.

[Gtk set_decorated function](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkwindow.html#method-gtkwindow--set-decorated)

Comment: Thanks, but if you can see in the screenshot there's some pudding btw the title of the window and the menubar. And i cant remove it :/

Comment: Does that mean you want the titlebar removed or not ?  And by "pudding" do you mean the window close icon ?  And what OS is it anyway ?

Comment: Non i don't to remove it, bettween the Titlebar and the menubar there's some free space that i don't want.  And sorry i meant *Padding; i'm using Fedora 23 with GTK 3.18